# Swift - Print array on table view descending

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm new to Swift and am currently trying to print an array in a Table View. The code works fine, but it is printed ascending (the first cell is index 0). Is there a way to print it descending (first cell shall be last index)?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I reckon this is the code responsible for the table:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let gefahren = gefahreneKm[indexPath.row]
        let dateFinal = date[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell") as! TimelineCell

        cell.setDrivenKm(gefahreneKm: gefahren)
        cell.setDate(date: dateFinal)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Sort the array you use for the data source.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you please illustrate it in an answer below? The array is updated dynamically by user input.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reversed` version of the array.

```
let gefahren = gefahreneKm.reversed()[indexPath.row]
let dateFinal = date.reversed()[indexPath.row]
```

I don't necessarily recommend doing this, though. You should probably reverse the array when you first create it. Either that or create a helper function for getting the value by index path so that you don't forget at some point to reverse the array.

```
func gefahren(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Gefahren {
    return gefahreneKm.reversed()[indexPath.row]
}
```

The downside is that in this context `reversed()` will actually create a new, reversed array, rather than giving you back the `ReversedCollection` (since it can't be indexed by `Int`), so performance will be bad. Best to just reverse at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! I've added my working code to the initial question.

Comment: Sort the array once when it's loaded or updated, not for every single access. Plus you are putting logic where it doesn't belong. What if the user can select the order of the table view? Adding `reversed` on every access is inefficient and prevents flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the most efficient way to do this, but without seeing the rest of the code, it should get the ball rolling for you:

```
let gefahreneKmIndex = gefahreneKm.count - 1 - indexPath.row
let dateFinalIndex = date.count - 1 - indexPath.row

let gefahren - gefahreneKm[gefahreneKmIndex]
let dateFinal = date[dateFinalIndex]
```

---

Alternatively, you could forget the code I included above and just reverse the array wherever you set its contents by using Swift's built-in `reversed()` method. Here's a basic example:

```
let arr = Array([0, 1 ,2 ,3].reversed()) // This will be ordered as [3, 2, 1, 0]
```

You would **NOT** want to do this inside of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {...}` because it get's called so often. Doing so would be extremely inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've added my working code to the initial question - regarding efficiency - is my approach acceptable?